# How to scale binary array keeping the values

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am looking to scale the array to a given length.

First Array [A] contains only 0 and 1 values and has constant size for example 8.

On the other hand, I have an array [B] of variable length depending on the operation of the program. I would like to compare both index by index.  Array [A] can be understood as the pattern while B is the data stretched over time. The result is to be the difference between the pattern and the data

```
A = [0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1]
B = [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
```

The situation in which:
B.size % A.size == 0 is simple but I can not assume it.

The first solution that came to my mind is to find the smallest common multiple and to scale both tables to it but I'm afraid that it would be very inefficient.

I am looking for a solution that will scale the [A] to size of [B] with the best possible accuracy. I write the program in c ++ but I will be grateful for all the tips.

Comment: You can still compare the "arrays", if you go from right-to-left direction instead. Otherwise copy `A` to a new "array" (vector?) and add leading zeros until the length is the same as `B`.

Comment: I do not use vectors. This solution will not pass if the difference between lengths will be big for example 8 and 999. In the best simple case `A = [0, 1] B = [0 ,0 ,0, 1, 1, 1]` program should return that there is no difference between arrays.

Comment: what's the o/p when `B = [0 ,0 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 0]` in the above comment example?

Comment: Well you seem to have contradicting requirements: You can't *scale* the data while "keeping the values". Also, you say that `B` (in your example) is "the data **stretched** over time" (emphasis mine). How is this *stretching* done? Can't you apply this stretching immediately instead of doing it "over time"?

Comment: @SparKot this is the question what method use to maintaining high accuracy. In this case program can return the difference = 1 but I care about finding a pattern faithfully

Comment: `B` is a collection of data collected over time. Time is not constant so `B` will be able to have different lengths. I need look for  `A` pattern in `B`.

Comment: For pattern-matching you don't need to "stretch" or "scale" the pattern, in fact hat would be counterproductive. If you want to find the pattern `A` in `B` there are quite a few algorithms available, if you only search a little (hint: use *pattern matching* as part of the search terms).

Comment: Thanks, I will search for solution on another way. I am not convinced or do not understand if the pattern search is enough. In other words, I am trying to say whether A is B which expands in time, not whether A is part of B (just for sure). So in simple example: `A =[0, 1, 0] B = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]` `A` and `B` are "equal". In fact I do not need to scale `A` array but if I know the pattern on how to do it, I will know what value under `A` should be under `B [i] `to compare whether there is compatibility here. Of course, I can do it in a bad way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two different problems, one is to stretch vector A to match the size of vector B (vector not in the C++ sense) and then to find a comparison function that tests if the resulting vector is similar enough to be considered equal. For the first part, here is an approach that calculates a factor by which an index in A needs to be multiplied to be projected onto an index in B.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int NumA = 8;
    const int NumB = 11;

    int a[NumA] = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };
    int b[NumB] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };

    int a2b[NumB]; // a stretched to size of b

    // factor to calculate a 'stretched a' index in a2b
    double factor = NumB / (double)NumA;
    int lastIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NumA; i++)
    {
        int index0 = (int)(i * factor); // where the next value is stored
        int index1 = (int)((i+1) * factor); // 'stretch' the value up to here
        for (int j = index0; j < index1; j++)
        {
            a2b[j] = a[i];
            lastIndex = j;
        }
    }
    for (++lastIndex; lastIndex < NumB; lastIndex++)
    {
        // fill last value gap, if any, due to float truncation
        a2b[lastIndex] = a[NumA - 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NumB; i++)
        std::cout << a2b[i] << " ";

    std::cout << endl;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

As you can see, it is not an exact match for B. For `A = [0, 1] B = [0 ,0 ,0, 1, 1, 1]` the output is

```
0 0 0 1 1 1
```

This does not address the second part of the problem, that is, determining equality. The logic chosen for the equality test may well change the approach for stretching the vector.